# string.decode custom errors argument

Tags: python

I have this Python 2.7 code:

```
# coding: utf-8
#
f = open('data.txt', 'r')

for line in f:
  line = line.decode(encoding='utf-8', errors='foo23')
  print len(line)

f.close()
```

How come Python won't issue an error since the only valid/registered codecs for errors are:

- strict
- ignore
- replace
- xmlcharrefreplace
- backslashreplace

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode) says that you can register your own, but I did not register 'foo23', and the Python code still runs without an error/warning. If I change the encoding argument it raises an error, but if I change errors to a custom string everything is ok.

```
line = line.decode(encoding='utf-9', errors='foo23')

 File "parse.py", line 7, in <module>
line = line.decode(encoding='utf-9', errors='foo23')
LookupError: unknown encoding: utf-9
```

Comment: foo23 doesn't trigger errors because there are no any errors while decodes to utf-8 so foo23 is wasn't used

Comment: I saved character 'š' to file and saved as iso-8859-2 encoding. Then I ran python code. When decoding there was an error, since it's saved as iso-8859-2 and we read it as utf-8. But there is no errohandler and it says: LookupError: unknown error handler name 'foo23'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there is no error during decoding; the `errors` parameter is not used and its value doesn't matter as long as it is a string:

```
>>> b'\x09'.decode('utf-8', errors='abc')
u'\t'
```

If bytes can't by decoded using the given encoding then the error handler is used and you get an error if you specify non-existing error handler:

```
>>> b'\xff'.decode('utf-8', errors='abc')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "../lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
LookupError: unknown error handler name 'abc'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `errors` keywork argument is for you to tell the `str.decode()` function how you want errors handled, it won't raise any all by itself. The reason you're getting an error on your second example is because you've passed an invalid argument for `encoding` to the function, and for no other reason.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [jfs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14622761), you most likely do not get an error when providing an invalid error handler because Python is not checking if the error handler is valid when there is no error in decoding.

However, it is worth noting that this behavior is implementation-dependent. As you have seen, in CPython, the `encode` and `decode` functions do not check for the existence of an error handler until an error is encountered.

In contrast, in IronPython, the `encode` and `decode` functions check for the existence of the specified error handler before attempting to encode/decode, and, thus, the example code you gave produces an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\code.py", line 6, in <module>
LookupError: unknown error handler name 'foo23'
```

Of course, other Python implementations may have different behavior in this situation.

---

I wanted to verify that CPython was, in fact, waiting to verify the error handler until a decoding error was encountered and that IronPython was not, so I checked the source code for both implementations.

## CPython

Below is the code for the `PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8Stateful` function found in the `unicodeobject.c` file for Python 2.6.2. This function appears to do most of the work decoding UTF-8 encoded bytes.

```c
PyObject *PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8Stateful(const char *s,
                                       Py_ssize_t size,
                                       const char *errors,
                                       Py_ssize_t *consumed)
{
    const char *starts = s;
    int n;
    Py_ssize_t startinpos;
    Py_ssize_t endinpos;
    Py_ssize_t outpos;
    const char *e;
    PyUnicodeObject *unicode;
    Py_UNICODE *p;
    const char *errmsg = "";
    PyObject *errorHandler = NULL;
    PyObject *exc = NULL;

    /* Note: size will always be longer than the resulting Unicode
       character count */
    unicode = _PyUnicode_New(size);
    if (!unicode)
        return NULL;
    if (size == 0) {
        if (consumed)
            *consumed = 0;
        return (PyObject *)unicode;
    }

    /* Unpack UTF-8 encoded data */
    p = unicode->str;
    e = s + size;

    while (s < e) {
        Py_UCS4 ch = (unsigned char)*s;

        if (ch < 0x80) {
            *p++ = (Py_UNICODE)ch;
            s++;
            continue;
        }

        n = utf8_code_length[ch];

        if (s + n > e) {
            if (consumed)
                break;
            else {
                errmsg = "unexpected end of data";
                startinpos = s-starts;
                endinpos = size;
                goto utf8Error;
            }
        }

        switch (n) {

        case 0:
            errmsg = "unexpected code byte";
            startinpos = s-starts;
            endinpos = startinpos+1;
            goto utf8Error;

        case 1:
            errmsg = "internal error";
            startinpos = s-starts;
            endinpos = startinpos+1;
            goto utf8Error;

        case 2:
            if ((s[1] & 0xc0) != 0x80) {
                errmsg = "invalid data";
                startinpos = s-starts;
                endinpos = startinpos+2;
                goto utf8Error;
            }
            ch = ((s[0] & 0x1f) << 6) + (s[1] & 0x3f);
            if (ch < 0x80) {
                startinpos = s-starts;
                endinpos = startinpos+2;
                errmsg = "illegal encoding";
                goto utf8Error;
            }
            else
                *p++ = (Py_UNICODE)ch;
            break;

        case 3:
            if ((s[1] & 0xc0) != 0x80 ||
                (s[2] & 0xc0) != 0x80) {
                errmsg = "invalid data";
                startinpos = s-starts;
                endinpos = startinpos+3;
                goto utf8Error;
            }
            ch = ((s[0] & 0x0f) << 12) + ((s[1] & 0x3f) << 6) + (s[2] & 0x3f);
            if (ch < 0x0800) {
                /* Note: UTF-8 encodings of surrogates are considered
                   legal UTF-8 sequences;

                   XXX For wide builds (UCS-4) we should probably try
                   to recombine the surrogates into a single code
                   unit.
                */
                errmsg = "illegal encoding";
                startinpos = s-starts;
                endinpos = startinpos+3;
                goto utf8Error;
            }
            else
                *p++ = (Py_UNICODE)ch;
            break;

        case 4:
            if ((s[1] & 0xc0) != 0x80 ||
                (s[2] & 0xc0) != 0x80 ||
                (s[3] & 0xc0) != 0x80) {
                errmsg = "invalid data";
                startinpos = s-starts;
                endinpos = startinpos+4;
                goto utf8Error;
            }
            ch = ((s[0] & 0x7) << 18) + ((s[1] & 0x3f) << 12) +
                ((s[2] & 0x3f) << 6) + (s[3] & 0x3f);
            /* validate and convert to UTF-16 */
            if ((ch < 0x10000)        /* minimum value allowed for 4
                                         byte encoding */
                || (ch > 0x10ffff))   /* maximum value allowed for
                                         UTF-16 */
            {
                errmsg = "illegal encoding";
                startinpos = s-starts;
                endinpos = startinpos+4;
                goto utf8Error;
            }
#ifdef Py_UNICODE_WIDE
            *p++ = (Py_UNICODE)ch;
#else
            /*  compute and append the two surrogates: */

            /*  translate from 10000..10FFFF to 0..FFFF */
            ch -= 0x10000;

            /*  high surrogate = top 10 bits added to D800 */
            *p++ = (Py_UNICODE)(0xD800 + (ch >> 10));

            /*  low surrogate = bottom 10 bits added to DC00 */
            *p++ = (Py_UNICODE)(0xDC00 + (ch & 0x03FF));
#endif
            break;

        default:
            /* Other sizes are only needed for UCS-4 */
            errmsg = "unsupported Unicode code range";
            startinpos = s-starts;
            endinpos = startinpos+n;
            goto utf8Error;
        }
        s += n;
        continue;

      utf8Error:
        outpos = p-PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(unicode);
        if (unicode_decode_call_errorhandler(
                errors, &errorHandler,
                "utf8", errmsg,
                starts, size, &startinpos, &endinpos, &exc, &s,
                &unicode, &outpos, &p))
            goto onError;
    }
    if (consumed)
        *consumed = s-starts;

    /* Adjust length */
    if (_PyUnicode_Resize(&unicode, p - unicode->str) < 0)
        goto onError;

    Py_XDECREF(errorHandler);
    Py_XDECREF(exc);
    return (PyObject *)unicode;

  onError:
    Py_XDECREF(errorHandler);
    Py_XDECREF(exc);
    Py_DECREF(unicode);
    return NULL;
}
```

We can see that this function calls another function, `unicode_decode_call_errorhandler`, which is what actually uses the error handler. The code for the function is below

```c
static
int unicode_decode_call_errorhandler(const char *errors, PyObject **errorHandler,
                                     const char *encoding, const char *reason,
                                     const char *input, Py_ssize_t insize, Py_ssize_t *startinpos,
                                     Py_ssize_t *endinpos, PyObject **exceptionObject, const char **inptr,
                                     PyUnicodeObject **output, Py_ssize_t *outpos, Py_UNICODE **outptr)
{
    static char *argparse = "O!n;decoding error handler must return (unicode, int) tuple";

    PyObject *restuple = NULL;
    PyObject *repunicode = NULL;
    Py_ssize_t outsize = PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(*output);
    Py_ssize_t requiredsize;
    Py_ssize_t newpos;
    Py_UNICODE *repptr;
    Py_ssize_t repsize;
    int res = -1;

    if (*errorHandler == NULL) {
        *errorHandler = PyCodec_LookupError(errors);
        if (*errorHandler == NULL)
            goto onError;
    }

    if (*exceptionObject == NULL) {
        *exceptionObject = PyUnicodeDecodeError_Create(
            encoding, input, insize, *startinpos, *endinpos, reason);
        if (*exceptionObject == NULL)
            goto onError;
    }
    else {
        if (PyUnicodeDecodeError_SetStart(*exceptionObject, *startinpos))
            goto onError;
        if (PyUnicodeDecodeError_SetEnd(*exceptionObject, *endinpos))
            goto onError;
        if (PyUnicodeDecodeError_SetReason(*exceptionObject, reason))
            goto onError;
    }

    restuple = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(*errorHandler, *exceptionObject, NULL);
    if (restuple == NULL)
        goto onError;
    if (!PyTuple_Check(restuple)) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, &argparse[4]);
        goto onError;
    }
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(restuple, argparse, &PyUnicode_Type, &repunicode, &newpos))
        goto onError;
    if (newpos<0)
        newpos = insize+newpos;
    if (newpos<0 || newpos>insize) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_IndexError, "position %zd from error handler out of bounds", newpos);
        goto onError;
    }

    /* need more space? (at least enough for what we
       have+the replacement+the rest of the string (starting
       at the new input position), so we won't have to check space
       when there are no errors in the rest of the string) */
    repptr = PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(repunicode);
    repsize = PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(repunicode);
    requiredsize = *outpos + repsize + insize-newpos;
    if (requiredsize > outsize) {
        if (requiredsize<2*outsize)
            requiredsize = 2*outsize;
        if (_PyUnicode_Resize(output, requiredsize) < 0)
            goto onError;
        *outptr = PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(*output) + *outpos;
    }
    *endinpos = newpos;
    *inptr = input + newpos;
    Py_UNICODE_COPY(*outptr, repptr, repsize);
    *outptr += repsize;
    *outpos += repsize;
    /* we made it! */
    res = 0;

  onError:
    Py_XDECREF(restuple);
    return res;
}
```

Since `PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8Stateful` calls `unicode_decode_call_errorhandler` with a `NULL` error handler, `unicode_decode_call_errorhandler` calls `PyCodec_LookupError`, which is what ultimately verifies the provided error handler. See the code below.

```c
PyObject *PyCodec_LookupError(const char *name)
{
    PyObject *handler = NULL;

    PyInterpreterState *interp = PyThreadState_GET()->interp;
    if (interp->codec_search_path == NULL && _PyCodecRegistry_Init())
    return NULL;

    if (name==NULL)
    name = "strict";
    handler = PyDict_GetItemString(interp->codec_error_registry, (char *)name);
    if (!handler)
    PyErr_Format(PyExc_LookupError, "unknown error handler name '%.400s'", name);
    else
    Py_INCREF(handler);
    return handler;
}
```

Note that the code in `PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8Stateful` that calls `unicode_decode_call_errorhandler` is under the utf8Error label, which is only reachable when errors are encountered in decoding.

---

## IronPython

In IronPython 2.7.9, decoding is handled in the `StringOps.DoDecode` function (in `StringOps.cs`) below.

```cs
internal static string DoDecode(CodeContext context, string s, string errors, string encoding, Encoding e, bool final, out int numBytes) {
    byte[] bytes = s.MakeByteArray();
    int start = GetStartingOffset(e, bytes);
    numBytes = bytes.Length - start;

#if FEATURE_ENCODING
    // CLR's encoder exceptions have a 1-1 mapping w/ Python's encoder exceptions
    // so we just clone the encoding & set the fallback to throw in strict mode.
    e = (Encoding)e.Clone();

    switch (errors) {
        case "backslashreplace":
        case "xmlcharrefreplace":
        case "strict": e.DecoderFallback = final ? DecoderFallback.ExceptionFallback : new ExceptionFallBack(numBytes, e is UTF8Encoding); break;
        case "replace": e.DecoderFallback = ReplacementFallback; break;
        case "ignore": e.DecoderFallback = new PythonDecoderFallback(encoding, s, null); break;
        default:
            e.DecoderFallback = new PythonDecoderFallback(encoding, s, LightExceptions.CheckAndThrow(PythonOps.LookupEncodingError(context, errors)));
            break;
    }
#endif

    string decoded = e.GetString(bytes, start, numBytes);

#if FEATURE_ENCODING
    if (e.DecoderFallback is ExceptionFallBack fallback) {
        byte[] badBytes = fallback.buffer.badBytes;
        if (badBytes != null) {
            numBytes -= badBytes.Length;
        }
    }
#endif

    return decoded;
}
```

Here the `DoDecode` function is creating the error handler in the `switch` statement before decoding. If the string containing the name of the error handler (`errors`) is not one of the recognized built-in handlers, `DoDecode` creates a `PythonDecoderFallback` object with a Python function object retrieved from the dictionary of registerd error handlers through the `PythonOps.LookupEncodingError` function (shown below).

```cs
[LightThrowing]
internal static object LookupEncodingError(CodeContext/*!*/ context, string name) {
    Dictionary<string, object> errorHandlers = context.LanguageContext.ErrorHandlers;
    lock (errorHandlers) {
        if (errorHandlers.ContainsKey(name))
            return errorHandlers[name];
        else
            return LightExceptions.Throw(PythonOps.LookupError("unknown error handler name '{0}'", name));
    }
}
```

When `LookupEncodingError` cannot find an error handler with the given `name` in the `errorHandlers` dictionary, it "throws" a LookupError `LightException`—i.e., it creates a `LightException` object and returns it. This object is then checked by the `LightExceptions.CheckAndThrow` function, which ultimately produces the "unknown error handler name" error seen when calling `decode` with an invalid error handler in IronPython.

Again, all of this happens in `DoDecode` before the `Encoding` object's `GetString` method is called, so IronPython produces an error with an invalid error handler whether there is a decoding error or not.